# Ruby Gem "Databasedotcom" same object issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, databasedotcom-gem

I am using the Ruby Gem "Databasedotcom" to integrate Salesforce in a Rails app and all works fine, but I now facing a problem with the same object name in the Rails application and Salesforce.

I have a User model in my Rails application and User object is also in Salesforce. So when trying to get data from Salesforce User object it always return the Rails application User object.

Here is my code

```
client = Databasedotcom::Client.new
client.client_id      #=> foo
client.client_secret  #=> bar

client.authenticate :username => "foo@bar.com", :password => "ThePasswordTheSecurityToken"  #=> "the-oauth-token"

client.materialize("User");

@user = User.find_by_Id('005d0000001291x');
```

but above statement always use the User model from Rails.

I want to use the Salesforce User object to get its data.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first wrap up you SF code in a module like this:

```
module SF
  module Connection          
    def self.client
      @client = Databasedotcom::Client.new("config/salesforce.yml")
      @client.authenticate :username => SF_CONFIG['username'], :password => SF_CONFIG['password_with_token']
      @client
    end
  end
end
```

And create initializer where you specify module to use with `sobject_module` param:

config/salesforce.yml:

```
username: username
password_with_token: token
client_secret: secret
client_id: cliend_id
sobject_module : SF
```

Add initializer to config/initializers:

salesforce.rb:

```
SF_CONFIG = YAML.load_file('config/salesforce.yml') rescue nil
```

Now you can use User inside SF module and it will be SF User, not you AR one.

And also I highly recommend you to read the documentation, there are quite a lot methods that will help you make your SF code cleaner:
http://rubydoc.info/github/heroku/databasedotcom/master/frames

Good luck with SF!

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will implement this and let you if all work fine, thanks